# Trying to run a .exe with paremeters, getting error about elevation

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to run a .exe with parameters, but getting an error " The requested operation requires elevation'.

Can someone please help me with this?

```
Dim proc As New Process
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Pmall\PmallFontWatcherCLIENT\FontBucket\FONTREG32.EXE"
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/copy"
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
proc.Start()

Dim output As String = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
If output.Contains("Success Text") Then
    MessageBox.Show("Success")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Failed")
End If
proc.Dispose()
```

Comment: What happens when you run the same command line from a command prompt?

Comment: I am very sorry.... It appears that I did not enter the ticket correctly, the code part seems to be messy.

Comment: if i run via start/run, it works perfectly

Comment: if run from command prompt it does not work, executing from "run" works fine

Comment: Then it appears that the application is doing something that requires elevation. From the name (FONTREG32.EXE), it appears it's attempting to install fonts, which does in fact require elevated (administrator) privileges in Windows.

Comment: Is there a way to run this and specify a user/pass that has the required rights on the client to execute the function>

Comment: I have looked at impersonation, but a little confused on that.

Comment: You can add a manifest that indicates that it requires elevation, which will cause Windows to prompt for admin credentials (username and password). You should be able to find an example of doing so with a search of this site. I'd start with `[vb.net] admin manifest` or `[vb.net] elevation manifest` (including the [] brackets).

Comment: Thank you Ken for pointing me in the right direction! ........  I will begin investigating.

Comment: Have you tried putting your computer on a table to increase it's elevation? :)

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015 and 2017 you can add the manifest file to your project.

Right-click your project file on the Solution Explorer, select Add, then New item (or CTRL+SHIFT+A). There you can find Application Manifest File.

The file name is app.manifest.

Then add below line in the file (between "requestedPrivileges..." block):

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Then your app will run as administrator.